# Caesar Cipher - UI Issues

Tags: css, react-native, expo

Trying to create a Caesar Cipher in my expo app and the layout is just not quite right. I feel as though I've gone wrong somewhere with the calculations. There is also a rotation issue where it's highlighting the text and getting a little stuck when trying to move it. I've included the entire component so you can see everything that it is doing.

The idea is to build a working Caesar Cipher where both rings contain the letters of the alphabet and the user should be able to rotate the inner circle. The next part is being able to do something knowing that after so three moves "A" is represented by the letter "D".

```
import { View, Text, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

const Rounded = ({ outerRadius, innerRadius }) => {
  const [innerRotation, setInnerRotation] = useState(0);

  const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');

  const outerLetters = alphabet.map((letter, index) => {
    const angle = (-360 / alphabet.length) * index - 90;
    const x = outerRadius * Math.cos((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
    const y = outerRadius * Math.sin((angle * Math.PI) / 180);

    return (
      <Text
        key={index}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: outerRadius + x,
          top: outerRadius - y,
          fontSize: 18,
          textAlign: 'center',
        }}>
        {letter}
      </Text>
    );
  });

  const innerLetters = alphabet.map((letter, index) => {
    const angle = (-360 / alphabet.length) * index - 90 + innerRotation;
    const x = innerRadius * Math.cos((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
    const y = innerRadius * Math.sin((angle * Math.PI) / 180);

    return (
      <Text
        key={index}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: outerRadius + x,
          top: outerRadius - y,
          fontSize: 18,
          textAlign: 'center',
        }}>
        {letter}
      </Text>
    );
  });

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
      const xOrigin = outerRadius;
      const yOrigin = outerRadius;

      const xTouch = xOrigin + gestureState.dx;
      const yTouch = yOrigin - gestureState.dy;

      const angleRadians = Math.atan2(yTouch - yOrigin, xTouch - xOrigin);
      const angleDegrees = (angleRadians * 180) / Math.PI;

      setInnerRotation(-angleDegrees + 90);
    },
  });

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        width: outerRadius * 2,
        height: outerRadius * 2,
        backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
        borderRadius: outerRadius,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#B2B0B0',
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: outerRadius - innerRadius,
          left: outerRadius - innerRadius,
          width: innerRadius * 2,
          height: innerRadius * 2,
          backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
          borderRadius: innerRadius,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#B2B0B0',
        }}>
        <View {...panResponder.panHandlers}>{innerLetters}</View>
      </View>
      {outerLetters}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Rounded;
```

As you can see from the calculations it is correctly being displayed as an equal circle but it doesn't fit inside the circles. I tried changing the dimensions too but I'm afraid it doesn't help the situation either.

Here is the code for how it's called too:

```
<Rounded outerRadius={125} innerRadius={100} />
```

[image]